# Calculating $\int\frac{e^{at}\cos(at)}{\sin t}dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Calculate $$\int\frac{e^{at}\cos(at)}{\sin t}dt.$$

Which way should I follow to solve this?  At least in approach.  There is no complete integration.  Laplace etc doesn't work either.  Should I approach serial?

Answer (score 0):

Even for $a=1$ there is no closed form solution and, as soon as $a \neq 0$, you face gaussian hypergeometric functions.

For a series solution, consider that, by composition of Taylor series
$$\csc (t) \cos (a t)=\frac 1 t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n t^n$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{-\frac{3 a^2+5}{6} ,0,\frac{15
   \left(a^2-2\right) a^2+7}{360} ,0,\frac{31-21 a^2 \left(a^4-5
   a^2+7\right)}{15120},\cdots\right\}$$ Integrating termwise, you will have
$$\int\frac{e^{at}\cos(at)}{\sin (t)}dt=\text{Ei}(a t)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\int e^{at}\, t^n \,dt$$ and the last integrals correspond to the incomplete gamma function.